# Linux photo manager with search capabilities for large photo collection

Tags: linux, photography, file-search

I'm looking for a Linux for a decent photo manager that will be able to work with local storage (NAS). Just a few requirements:

- index large photo/video collection (> 100k photos)
- search by EXIF metadata / keywords
- photo tagging
- grouping photos into collections
- exporting photos

I've tried darktable/digikam but I'm not very happy with that. No need to a full photo (RAW) editor with Lightroom capabilities.

Comment: You should explain why you are not happy with darktable and digikam.

Comment: @pLumo Terrible UX. I gotta admit I haven't tested the latest versions, only what's available in Ubuntu apt repositories. Darktable doesn't really have seach capabilities which is ok for a RAW editor. digikam is trying to bundle too many features into a single program, it's slow to respond and often not responding.

Comment: gThumb might fulfill most of your requirements, although the performance with very large folders may depend on the speed of the filesystem/PC I'm afraid.

Comment: @Sebastian Thanks, gThumb looks promising. Search capabilities are quite limited, but browsing seems to be fast.